# How can I add text to a live video stream from USB webcam which is being transcoded on the fly with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, arch-linux, gpu, webcam

How can I add text to a live video stream from USB webcam which is being transcoded on the fly with FFmpeg?

Here is the code which is being transcoded from two GPUs, I was not able to add texts using drawtext video filter:

```
ffmpeg -init_hw_device cuda=decdev:/dev/dri/renderD129 -init_hw_device vaapi=encdev:/dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_device decdev -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v mjpeg_cuvid -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video4 -filter_hw_device encdev -vf 'hwdownload,format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v hevc_vaapi -b:v 2M -rc_mode 2 -qp 20 -level 4.1 -f segment -segment_time 600 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 Kitchen/"(%b-%-d-%Y-%a)_%-I::%M::%S::%p.mp4" -y
```

Edit:

Here is the code where I do not get errors, but FFMPEG does not display or write the texts to the video file:

```
ffmpeg -init_hw_device cuda=decdev:/dev/dri/renderD129 -init_hw_device vaapi=encdev:/dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_device decdev -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v mjpeg_cuvid -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video2 -filter_hw_device encdev -vf 'hwdownload,format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v hevc_vaapi -b:v 2M -rc_mode 2 -qp 20 -level 4.1 -f segment -segment_time 600 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 Living_Room/"(%b-%-d-%Y-%a)_%-I::%M::%S::%p.mp4" -vf "drawtext=text='My text starting at 640x360':x=640:y=360:fontsize=60:fontcolor=blue" -y
```

Comment: Can you add the text using software decoder and encoder (without VAAPI and CUDA)?

Comment: Hello, Rotem. Yes, I was able to do so: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/wnCgzR6q)

Comment: `drawtext` is not hardware accelerated filter. Try something like: `-vf 'hwdownload,format=rgb24,drawtext...,format=nv12,hwupload'`